# Keras incompatible input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, shapes, python-3.8

I am using Keras to make a prediction model. But when I try to get the prediction, I get a ValueError indicating that the input is incompatible. Here is a minimal code that is reproducing the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import pickle

#Bring data:
Name = "Predict-{}".format(int(time.time()))
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(Name))


pickle_in = open("training_data.pickle","rb")
training_data = pickle.load(pickle_in)


random.shuffle(training_data)
X=[]
y=[]
for file_data, categ in training_data :
    X.append(file_data)
    y.append(categ)
  
X=np.array(X)
y=np.array(y)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(172,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X,y,epochs=10, batch_size=128,validation_split=0.25, callbacks=[tensorboard])

#New input Xnew, with len(Xnew)=172
Xnew = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
```

Here is the error I got :

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_107 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 172 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

The model summary :

```
Model: "sequential_53"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_53 (Flatten)         (None, 172)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_109 (Dense)            (None, 172)               29756     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_110 (Dense)            (None, 2)                 346       
=================================================================
Total params: 30,102
Trainable params: 30,102
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I also don't understand why the shape is (None, 172) and not 172.

Comment: what is X.shape and y.shape ?

Comment: @SreeramTP for X: (602, 172) . And for y: (602,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies on the object you give to the network in order to predict. It expects an array as `(batch, data)`, you are giving a `(,data)`.

What you could do is just saying to the network "here I have one batch"

```py
Xnew = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
ynew = model.predict(np.expand_dims(Xnew, axis=0))
```

expand_dims add a dimension (in this case in front of the shape)

And for the last part, you get `(None, 172)` None means that we don't know the number of batch in the summary (you can specify it if you want), the network is expecting (X, 172), with X that can be everything (32, 64 ...)

Comment: Thank you. It works.
But I don't really understand what the batch is. 
I am new to Keras and have never seen the batch before.

Comment: batch_size determines how many data points in used to train the model for a step

Comment: You should look on google what is a batch, an iteration, an epoch ... batch is just the number of example you give to the network in each step of the training so for example if you have 2000 examples of 172 elements, you can give it to the network 32 by 32, when you give all the 2000 examples, you have achieved an epoch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for flatten layer in the model as your data is already in the correct shape for Dense layer.

So you can re-write the model like this,

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=(172,), units=172, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Note the input_shape parameter in the first Dense layer. It tells the model how much dimensions to expect.

Model summary will look like this,

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 172)               29756     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 346       
=================================================================
Total params: 30,102
Trainable params: 30,102
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Training model using random data of same shape as your data,

```
X = np.random.rand(*(602, 172))
y = np.random.rand(*(602, 2))

model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

Epoch 1/100
19/19 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6006 - accuracy: 0.9934
Epoch 2/100
19/19 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6006 - accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 3/100
19/19 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6006 - accuracy: 0.9983
```

Regarding None in the output shape, None means this dimension is variable.

The first dimension in a keras model is always the batch size. You don't need fixed batch sizes, unless in very specific cases (for instance, when working with stateful=True LSTM layers).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! it helped making the model better.